# Issue in OpenAM Forgotten Password RestAPI from Java

Tags: openam

> Hi I have gone through the documentaion given in https://forgerock.org/openam/doc/bootstrap/user-self-service-guide/index.html#configuring-forgotten-password

The API is working fine from poster and postman . But when tring from java using http it not working ,internal server is getting . What will be the probelm ? pls help .

```
public static void main(String a[]) throws IOException { 
    JSONObject data1 = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject data = new JSONObject();

    data.put("queryFilter", "mail eq 'test@gmail.com'");
    data1.put("input", data);
    System.out.println(data1);

    Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();


      HttpURLConnection connection = null;

    try {

        URL obj = new URL("http://localhost:8080/sso/json/sample/selfservice"
       + "/forgottenPassword?_action=submitRequirements");
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        if (headers != null && headers.size() > 0) {
            Iterator it = headers.entrySet().iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry) it.next();
                connection.setRequestProperty((String) pair.getKey(),
                        (String) pair.getValue());
            }
        }
        // Send request
        DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(
                connection.getOutputStream());


        dataOutputStream.writeBytes(data1.toString());
        dataOutputStream.flush();
        dataOutputStream.close();

        // Get Response
        System.out.println(connection.getResponseCode());
        System.out.println(connection.getResponseMessage());

        InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String line;

        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(line);
            response.append('\r');
        }
        rd.close();
        is.close();
        return response.toString();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        LOG.info("Error in sendPost : MalformedURLException " + e);
        throw e;
    } catch (ProtocolException e) {
        LOG.info("Error in sendPost : ProtocolException " + e);
        throw e;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        LOG.info("Error in sendPost : IOException "
                + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        LOG.info("Error in sendPost : IOException " + e);
        throw e;
    } finally {
        if (connection != null) {
            connection.disconnect();
        }
    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to set the Accept-Language header on the request with a supported locale.